# vsto excel 2010 add in - get value of cell when contents refer to another cell and formula

Tags: excel, add-in

I'm trying to get the value of a cell using this:
    Globals.Sheet3.Cells.Range["A2"].Value2 as string;
Cell A2 refers to a cell on a different sheet that in turn refers to a formula on another sheet. The code above always returns null. How can I get the text of cell a2?

Answer (score 1):

If you use...

VB.Net

```
Dim res As String
res = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value2.ToString()
```

C#

```
String res = "";
res = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet3"].Range("A2").Value2.ToString()
```

Does that work?

It's not clear from the question if the problem is with a section of VB.Net or C# code, however I'd say the problem is either with the way your a using the Range method, or possibly with your use of the Globals object.

UPATE to QUESTION:
Based on feedback from the questioner, the ANSWER to this question is to use code such as...
C#

```
String res = "";
res = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet3"].Range("A2").Text
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with the original post. The solution turned out to be simple - I replaced .value2 with .text and it returned the correct value.